# @angular/core/core has no exported member 'StaticProvider'

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular and I just followed the steps from the [NGX website](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) itself. The installation command was showing this error

"The specified command add is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`."

So i used

> npm install ngx-bootstrap --save

And then added

> ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css

to my angular-cli.json

--

My Angular version --

@angular/cli: 1.4.10

node: 10.15.0

os: win32 x64

--
The error flashes when i compile my code after importing BsDatePickerModule-

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
```

and then update the imports--

```
imports: [BrowserModule,
  BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()],
```

```js
//MY PACKAGE.JSON

{
  "name": "date-picker",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

```js
module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
  BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
  
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
angular-cli.json



{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "date-picker"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        
        "styles.css",
        " ../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
      ],
      "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the link to the website you were following, we are also going to need to see your `app.module.ts`

Comment: I's a good idea not to use uppercase letters in internet forums...

Comment: @SmokeyDawson i have updated.

Comment: @KamilNaja sorry this was my first question on any forum. i have updated it though. Thanks.

Comment: i think if down to a mismatch in the angular versions you are using can you try and update the project once again or just try a fresh using cli. for a hint you can check this working link `https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker`

Comment: @RahulSingh I re-created a project. after it was completed i installed ngx-bootstrap with "npm install ngx-bootstrap --save" the version i got was  "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0" then i used the code you shared but still i am getting the same error along with --Metadata version mismatch for module /Desktop/workspace/datePicker/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in src/app/app.module.ts,

Comment: i thing yiu need to delete the ngx globally using the `-g` command and then install